# get ONLY authors for wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to somehow get all of the authors for a wordpress blog, not the users. When i used wp_list_authors() it times out because there are over 50,000 users normally. How can i go about ONLY getting authors who publish data on the blog?

Answer (score 3):

In the options array you pass to the `wp_list_authors()` function, you need to set `hide_empty` to `true`. This will exclude all authors with 0 posts.

See the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors).

Example:

```
<?php
    wp_list_authors(array('hide_empty' => true));
?>
```

Comment: still times out... not really sure why

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points to be made here to address your problem.
Only users with the title of 'author' and above can author a post on a wordpress site.
If you examine the wordpress documentation for the wp_list_authors() function you will learn that the hide_empty parameter has a default of 1(true) so it is not nessicary to declare it in the function call.  I setup a test on my local server and found that the function works in all of the following ways as predicted in the documentation.

```
<?php 
wp_list_authors('hide_empty=1');               //wordpress example
wp_list_authors(array('hide_empty' => true));  //Alex
wp_list_authors();                             //Best
?>
```

All of which will only show authors that have contributed a minimum of one post in a list format.
Are there any additional details you may have left out?